# Hasura limit data based on field

Tags: graphql, hasura

I am looking for a way to put a constraint in place preventing access to data based on a **site_uuid**.

All the tables in my database would have a field **site_uuid**. Then I would ideally like to pass that **site_uuid** as a request header and essentially apply a where clause on every query checking the **site_uuid** is valid for the dataset return.

The idea is that its a shared database with multiple "sites". I understand scalability issues etc. This is not an issue in my case, the best approach is this multi-tenant approach if I can make it work.

I first hit this issue using the built-in _by_pk queries, when returning one object. I understand I can just use a where clause when returning a list of records.

Comment: You are looking for Hasura ACL. Check this blog post
https://hasura.io/blog/authorization-rules-for-multi-tenant-system-google-cloud/

Comment: Have a look at these two articles: (1) https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/manual/auth/authorization/common-roles-auth-examples.html#managers-of-an-organisation-in-a-multi-tenant-app and (2) https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/manual/auth/authorization/roles-variables.html#roles-session-variables

Comment: Looks to be exactly what I needed, will review and post an answer when I can